# Titchmarsh S function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

SO it is known that Titchmarsh S function $$ S(T)= \pi^{-1} arg\quad \zeta\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+iT\bigg)$$ under the assumption of *riemann hypothesis * gives $$ S(T)=O(\frac{\log T}{\log \log T})$$ can someone guide me its proof !

Comment: So i encountered this theorem while studying the paper of Ankeny(1951) [link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969420?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) , his paper assumes this result (though for L functions rather than $\zeta$) its solution is also in Titchmarsh's theory of riemann zeta function [link](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/The%20Theory%20Of%20The%20Riemann%20Zeta-Function%20-Titshmarch.pdf) in last chapter but i munable to understand that.